# How to find rows with exact same value in one or more columns

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi I'd like to know how can I find in PHP-MySQL all the rows that have the same value in one column or more than one. The value doesn't have to be specified, so I wanna find ALL the rows that have a value that is not unique in the table (meaning there is at least another row with the same value).

For examle the table columns are `ID | number | value`

And the rows are:

`1 | 5 | hello`
`2 | 6 | goodbye`
`3 | 7 | see you`
`4 | 6 | hello`
`5 | 6 | goodbye`

I would like a query to find all the rows that have the same value in the field `value`, so in this case the results would be rows 1,4 and 2,4

Also I would like a query to find all the rows that have the same value in both fields `number` and `value`, so in the example the result would be just rows 2,4

I need to retrieve all the rows that I find so `SELECT DISTINCT` doesn't fit since I would only retrieve the common value and not the entire row.

Comment: Homework? GROUP BY can be used, or EXISTS, or self join.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT ID, number, value
FROM mytable
WHERE value IN (SELECT value
                FROM mytable
                GROUP BY value
                HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2)
```

and this for the second case:

```
SELECT ID, number, value
FROM mytable
WHERE (number, value) IN (SELECT number, value
                          FROM mytable
                          GROUP BY number, value
                          HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I'd also like to understand it, so... basically `GROUP BY....` is just a more complex condition and `HAVING COUNT` works as `WHERE` for the 'groupedby' fields?

Comment: @ErnieBob `GROUP BY` groups together all records sharing the same values in the fields specified in the `GROUP BY`. `HAVING` is applied at group level, so `COUNT(*)>=2` essentially means: get me all groups having a population that is equal or greater than `2`.

Comment: Oh ok so `group by` does precisely what i was looking for, it groups rows with the same value.. thank you very much, this couldn't have been more helpful :)

Comment: It didn't work, can you help me out?

table is `ev_links` and fields are `link_host` and `link_value`

query is:

`"
 
 SELECT * FROM ev_links 
 WHERE (link_host, link_value) IN (
  
  SELECT link_host, link_value 
  FROM ev_links
  GROUP BY link_host, link_value
  HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2
  
 )

"`

I checked and I'm sure there are rows with same values in both fields, yes it doesn't return any row.

Comment: @ErnieBob Can you setup an sqlfiddle demo with some sample data so that I can reproduce the issue?

Comment: I can't manage to create the schema... anyway table is this

`"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ev_links (
 
 ID INT(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    
 link_host VARCHAR( 255 ) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
 
 link_value VARCHAR( 255 ) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    
 PRIMARY KEY( ID )
 
)"`

and values could be

`1 | host1 | value1` , 
`2 | host1 | value2` ,
`3 | host2 | value2` , 
`4 | host1 | value1` , 

and of course it should return rows 1 and 4

Comment: Anyway i remind you i'm calling the query from php so maybe the syntax is a little bit different....

Comment: @ErnieBob I've tested my query with the data you provide and runs ok on my end.

Comment: @ErnieBob I haven't used php for quite a while. I executed the query from MySQL workbench. But there shouldn't be any problems with executing the query from php. Did you first try the query with a tool like MySQL workbench with your actual data?

Comment: No, anyway now I'm gonna try changing the query and see what happens, but I don't doubt your query works so... i'm just gonna find out what is the issue, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

One more way to do it using `exists`. This will output rows where the vals in different rows are equal,nums in different rows are equal, val-num combination on different rows if they are equal.

```
select * 
from tablename t
where exists (select 1 from tablename t1 
              where t.id <> t1.id and (t.val = t1.val or t.num = t1.num)
              )
```